# In JavaScript, why is a "reverse while" loop an order of magnitude faster than "for"?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, while-loop, v8

In these benchmarks, http://jsperf.com/the-loops, Barbara Cassani showed that a "reverse while" loop is way faster,

```
while (iterations > 0) {
    a = a + 1;
    a = a - 1;
    iterations--;
}
```

than a usual "for" loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    a = a + 1;
    a = a - 1;
}
```

Why?

**Update**

Okay, forget about it, there is a bug in the test, `iterations = 100`, is executed only once per page. Therefore reducing it, well, means that we don't really enter the loops. Sorry.

Comment: ***Way*** faster is a bit optimistic. We're talking about *millions* of operations here.

Comment: I would expect the physical architecture to be a part of it. Subtraction is faster than addition simply because a decrement causes a the physical size of the represented number to decrease. But I wouldn't expect the kind of difference those numbers suggest.

Comment: Sorry, but lolwut? (I'm talking about "a decrement causes a the physical size of the represented number to decrease").

Comment: Extra variable slows loop down, yes. http://jsperf.com/the-loops/8

Answer (score 2):

Except for the big bug in the initial test, here are the results:

- `for` vs `while` makes no difference
- but `>` or `<` are better than `!==`

http://jsperf.com/the-loops/15

Answer (score 1):

It is because of of specifics of internals of each JavaScript engine. Don't use it for optimization, because you can't logically count on it always be faster as engines change. For example, check out [last revision of test you've linked](http://jsperf.com/the-loops/8) and note that difference is much more smaller if exists at all on recent browsers.

Comment: It is way too consistent in all tested architectures (different magnitude, but "reverse while" always wins by a large margin). I'd rather go with @SomeGuy's observation that the additional variable is the culprit.

Comment: This is exactly what "specifics of internals" is. Intializer, logically, shouldn't slow each iteration. If it does right now, that's only because nobody bothered to optimize it, because gains are negligible (just try to measure how many exactly nanoseconds you lose on each iteration).