# three.js why does it use for loops instead of while

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, while-loop, three.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What loop is faster, while or for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629174/what-loop-is-faster-while-or-for)

I see in three.js that there is the common code feature in many languages:

```
for ( var i = 0, l = something.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    do some stuff over i
}
```

but I read that in javascript performance can be better by using:

```
var i = something.length;
while(i--){
    do some stuff over i
}
```

Does this actually improve any performance significantly? is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @user1689607: No, this is a language-specific question. That question is language-neutral.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Then we can pick another one from the list on the right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848552/in-javascript-why-is-a-reverse-while-loop-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than?rq=1

Comment: Where did you read that? http://jsperf.com/forvswhilee

Comment: @user1689607: From your second linked question: *"Okay, forget about it, there is a bug in the test"* Perfectly happy to believe this is a duplicate, but if so, let's identify it properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Many near dupes, not sure which one would count as exact, but the answer is nearly always the same... micro optimization, depends on implementation, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this actually improve any performance significantly?

No. Not reliably cross-browser (which is to say, across JavaScript implementations).

Moreover, note that in your example, your `while` loop loops backward (*n* to 0), the `for` loop you quote loops forward (0 to *n*). Sometimes it matters.

In general, micro-optimization is rarely appropriate, and this is *particularly* true in the case of JavaScript, where different implementations in the wild have markedly different performance characteristics. Instead, write code to be **clear** and maintainable, and address *specific* performance issues only if they arise, and if they arise address them on your target engines.

Comment: +1 The browser agnostic performance police rarely consider the fact that a single extra DOMReady event could account for 10 million for loops.